# Run Script with ESM in Forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, module, forever

How do I run a script with the option `-r esm` in Forever ?

with the configuration below, throws an error
Saying `Unexpected token import`

Config:

```
{
  "uid": "app",
  "script": "index.js",
  "sourceDir": "./",
  "args": ["-r", "esm"]
}
```

command: `forever start ./config.json`.

I have installed `esm` and if i run `node -r esm ./index.js` it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me after hours of searching.

```
sudo forever start -c "node -r esm" index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

`forever -c "node -r esm" src/server/app.js` works for me